# Long Press Enlarge Using Constraints Update

Tags: swift, layout, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a function that IS working but I do not understand why it works. I simply played with the values until it did what I wanted. I am asking for an explanation because I'm afraid that, if I do not understand how it works, it might behave in unpredictable ways at some point.

The code is run when the user does a long button press. The code then enlarges an image that had 30 leading space and 30 trailing space to the superview to have no leading space and no trailing space. Because the image already has a ratio constraint, the height increases to maintain the image's width/height ratio.

The thing I don't understand is why I only have to subtract 9 from each constraint to get it to approximately hug the superview edge but I have to add 30 to each to get it to return to the original size.

```
//LONG PRESS FUNCTION
//Scoring Page: Fact Section

var zoomState = ""

@IBOutlet var fctBx_Img_LeadingCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var fctBx_Img_TrailCon: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        if zoomState == "" {
            fctBx_Img_TrailCon.constant = -9
            fctBx_Img_LeadingCon.constant = -9
            zoomState = "zoomed"
        }
        else {
            fctBx_Img_TrailCon.constant = +30
            fctBx_Img_LeadingCon.constant = +30
            zoomState = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Details:
Using Xcode 6.4
Using Swift
Using storyboards
Using auto layout, iPhone only, portrait orientation only
I'm new to programming and app dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not subtracting the value -9 actually you are assigning it & the same goes for the addition part you are assigning +30. so it gets back to its normal value.